# Inner cursor performance issues

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, best-practices, cursors

Before I tried to [avoid using cursor](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Tips/tipCursor.htm) because of performance issues. But now I have to do some calculations to reach some goals. I have a stored procedure that has a code like this:

```
DECLARE  Outer_Cursor CURSOR FOR...

   OPEN Outer_Cursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM Outer_Cursor INTO ...

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN

      DECLARE  Inner_Cursor CURSOR  FOR...

      OPEN Outer_Cursor
      FETCH NEXT FROM Inner_Cursor INTO ...

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN

        ...

        FETCH NEXT FROM Inner_Cursor INTO ...
      END

      CLOSE Inner_Cursor
      DEALLOCATE Inner_Cursor    

      FETCH NEXT FROM Outer_Cursor INTO ...

  END

  CLOSE Outer_Cursor
  DEALLOCATE Outer_Cursor
```

My question is: is it possible to avoid (minimize) so expensive cursor recreation for inner cursor. How can I reuse inner cursor declaration, is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Without a bit more information, it's hard to know how to help you. The code you laid out looks like a fairly standard nested cursor implementation, but as you noted those can perform terribly. There may be a way to reach the same goal without nested cursors, even if it makes the code more complex.

Comment: @AJ01 I have to use inner cursor. :(

Comment: why do you *have" to use a cursor? You say you do (homework?) but why don't you give us the problem. Nested cursors will never run OK

Comment: @gbn homework?! :) no. nested code has a lot of logical expressions, multiply stored procedure calls. What should I do in this case? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest that instead of using the inner cursor, if you want to avoid its creation and release for every step of the outer cursor, to use a temp table to fetch data and truncate it for each step.

That way you'll create it just once, and the truncation operation is not logged, so it will not cause any problems.

PS: in this situation I'm always in favor of temp tables with an identity column that will be looped for each record (or batches :-).
But I agree with the comments, better tell us the problem and maybe we'll find another solution.

Comment: O! thanks! while (1 = 1)... I will compare these two variants.